# null in this code of javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
    Array.prototype.forEach = function(callback, context) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            callback.call(context || null, this[i], i, this);
        }
    };

    ["a", "b", "c"].forEach(function(value, index, array) {
        assert(value,
                "Is in position " + index + " out of " +
                        (array.length - 1));
    });
```

I don't fully understand why `null` is used here. I guess when I use the invoke `foreach`, if I miss the `context` parameter, it will replace it with `null`? Will `callback.call(context || null, this[i], i, this)` execute? Can someone explain this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't actually be there. `undefined` and `null` have the same effect when passed as the `this` argument to `Function.prototype.call` (the `this` argument of the function is set to `undefined`).

Comment: so even i pass null or undefined to Function.prototype.call, the Function.prototype.call still can execute ?

Comment: @joesmith: The `this` argument can take any value. In non-strict mode, if you pass `null` or `undefined` as the `this` argument, `this` will be `undefined` in the function.

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a falsy value for 'context', `(context || null)` will result in a null. JS will pass null as the first parameter into `callback.call()`. The first parameter is the `this` for the callback function.